# Uniform distribution on sphere

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $U = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ is random vector uniformly distributed on unit sphere $S^{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Are $u_1, u_2, u_3$ mutually independent ? I guess not, but I have no idea to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

A simple counter-example can show dependence. For example:

$P(0\lt u_1\lt \frac{1}{2} \;\cap\; 0\lt u_2\lt \frac{1}{2} \;\cap\; 0\lt u_3\lt \frac{1}{2}) = 0$

but

$P(0\lt u_1\lt \frac{1}{2})P(0\lt u_2\lt \frac{1}{2})P(0\lt u_3\lt \frac{1}{2}) \gt 0$.

Comment: Why is the first probability zero?  $(0, 1/2) \times (0, 1/2) \times (0, 1/2)$ is a region of the unit sphere.

Comment: @dsaxton Unit sphere refers to the sphere surface: all vectors must have length $1$.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mick A. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @dsaxton: If you were talking about a ball (including the inside) you could make the same argument with $ P (u_1\gt \frac{3}{4} \;\cap\; u_2\gt \frac{3}{4} \;\cap\; u_3\gt \frac{3}{4}) = 0$